# Can SpineJS block the UI when updating?

Tags: spine.js

One of the stated SpineJS goals is to make the entire UI non-blocking (i.e. display the change to the user, even though it might have not been updated successfully on the server side yet).

Can it be used in a standard "blocking" manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can. Look here under "callbacks":

http://spinejs.com/docs/ajax

You can basically block the UI at any point, and I do it for things that just can't be deferred to the server. Note that I don't even use the ajaxSucess() event, but just custom bindings for events. Here is an example use case in meta programming:

```
Bind 'clickHandlerFinish' event to clickHandlerFinishWork()
Bind 'click' event on button a to clickHandler()
User clicks on button a
clickHandler() gets fired
clickHandler disables the button and blocks the UI
clickHandler makes an AJAX call to the server to do work
(Remember UI is still blocked)
AJAX call finally returns, and fires the clickHandlerFinish() callback
clickHandlerFinish() unblocks the UI, re-enables the button, and presents the new changes
```

I've used this successfully on a few instances. Works great for me!